# How to prevent displaying multiple fragments over each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a multiple-dialog-fragment layout. In the large layout, I show them as dialogs and there's no problem:

```
fragment.show(fragmentManager, "fragment_dialog");
```

But in normal devices, I am using a fragment transaction and replace fragments as below:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The problem is that in normal devices, when I press the menu button twice (or more), the same fragment will be shown over the previous one. Is there a way to find out which fragment is visible right now and prevent it from opening again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, add tag to when you replace

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "fragment_foo")
           .commit(); // etc
```

then make a control

```
if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_foo") == null){
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find fragment by tag:

```
if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment_dialog") == null) {
//show dialog here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Replace fragmentCotainer with your container id
Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentCotainer);
// Return if the class are the same
if(currentFragment.getClass().equals(fragment.getClass())) return;